# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate i dont understand it at all

Tags: mongoose

Hi i got a problem with `findByIdAndUpdate`. What I am doing wrong?

```js
router.post('/add/:id', function(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  const task = NewTask(body);
  console.log(task);
  console.log(task.id);
  const updateObj = {
    description: task.description,
    selectValue: task.selectValue,
    timeToDo: task.timeToDo
  };
  console.log('Object:', updateObj);
  NewTask.findByIdAndUpdate(task.id, updateObj, { new: true });

  res.redirect('/tasks');
});
```

Comment: What type is NewTask, is it a schema or some object?

Comment: It is a schema .

Comment: You have to call the save function on NewTask, and then on the callback then you will have the ID on the newly saved document

Comment: Sorry i don't know how exacly should i do it. Could you write the code?

Comment: Check the answer I have posted, I am not sure if that is what you intend to do

Comment: I have updated the code, I had omitted something, the update should work, let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.post('/add/:id', function (req, res) {
   const body = req.body;
   const task = new NewTask(body);

   task.save((err, task) => {
   if(err) {
    console.log('There was an error saving the tack');
   } else {
     res.redirect('/tasks');
   }
 });
});

 router.post('/update/:id', function (req, res) {
   const body = req.body;
   const id = req.params.id;

   const updateObj = {
     description: body.description,
     selectValue: body.selectValue,
     timeToDo: body.timeToDo
   };

    console.log('Object:', updateObj);
    NewTask.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
   if(err) {
    console.log('There was an error updating task');
   } else {
     res.redirect('/tasks');
   }

   });

});

});
```

Comment: There is a problem with this code: 'TypeError: NewTask.save is not a function'

Comment: Ok it is working but i wanted to update the task i already had in body. Check this page: https://to-do-app-wojciech.herokuapp.com/   login:admin password: 123
I am working on button 'edit'

Comment: But why do you want to update it immediately after saving it?

Comment: Rather make changes to the req.body object and then save it with the updated object, you do not need to update the document in this end-point

Comment: If some write something wrong or want to change the date of task. For example task.description : ' Go to schoool'  - mistake it should be 'school' so if he click the button he can easily change it.

Comment: yeah thats what i want. but i dont know how to do it :D i dont understand findByIdAndUpdate from documentation

Comment: Then you should make a different end-point for that, meaning that you have to have another POST request to update the details

Comment: So it is not possible if i have id of task and i use findByIdAndUpdate to change description,date of this task but id will be the same ?

Comment: Yes it will be possible

Comment: So after saving the new task, you should respond to your front-end with the new task object and save it in the front-end state, and then when you need to update you can use the id from the front-end.

Comment: Note that the ID of the document will be '_id' instead of 'id'

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i think we didn't understand each other at all, but it works with your help now. Thats the finally code :

```
router.post('/add/:id', function (req, res) {
const body = req.body;
const id = req.params.id;
const updateObj = {
    description: body.description,
    selectValue: body.selectValue,
    timeToDo: body.timeToDo
};

console.log('Object:', updateObj);
NewTask.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error updating task');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/tasks');
    }
});
```

});